# specifics of raise_application_error in trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have strange beahvior of raise_application_error function in insert trigger comparing to plsql procedure. **sqlerrm** field get only error message in plsql error, but error text with stack trace from trigger. What is the reason?
(Oracle 10.2.0.4)

Here is test example.

First case: executing procedure from plsql:

```
declare
  procedure p_e as
  begin
    raise_application_error(-20110, 'error from procedure');
  end;
 begin
  p_e;
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    dbms_output.put_line('========================================');
    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
end;
```

and see

```
ORA-20110: error from procedure
========================================
ORA-06512: at line 4
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

Ok. This is what I expected.

Second case:
simple table

```
create table TT
(
  r NUMBER
);
```

and trigger

```
create or replace trigger t_tt
  before insert on tt  
  for each row
begin
  raise_application_error(-20110, 'error from trigger');
end t_tt;
```

Executing:

```
begin
  insert into TT
  values
    (0);
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    dbms_output.put_line('========================================');
    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
end;
```

end have such text:

```
ORA-20110: error from trigger
ORA-06512: at "GFU_PARUS.T_TT", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'GFU_PARUS.T_TT'
========================================
ORA-06512: at "GFU_PARUS.T_TT", line 2
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Answer (score 2):

[`SQLERRM`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/sqlerrm_function.htm#LNPLS01350) inside an exception handler will return the [error code and **nested** messages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS848) of the error stack (up to 512 bytes).

So in both cases of your question, `SQLERRM` returns the error stack: the first case being limited to a single error.

Oracle recommends to use [`DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_util.htm#ARPLS73242) if you want to retrieve the full error stack.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK returns the same like sqlerrm, so it cannot help. According to your links, sqlerrm contains nested messages, but not stack. Or Error ORA-04088 is "nested message"?.. So, main question is how can I get only the error text in my application? (except substr function)

Comment: Well, if you absolutely don't want to use `substr`, you could use [`regexp_substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303) instead I suppose :)